# Asynchronous Database call to MySql Database gives error

Tags: c#, mysql, async-await, enterprise-library

I am using Microsoft.Enterprise Library with MySql database.
I am trying to call a database method asynchronously.

My method is like below..

```
public static async Task<DataTable> ExecuteDataSetWithParameterAsSourceAsync(this Database database, CommandDetail cmdDetail, params Object[] parameterSource)
    {
        List<int> outParamIndex = new List<int>();

        AsyncCallback cb = new AsyncCallback(EndExecuteReaderCallBack);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DbAsyncState state = BeginExecuteReader(database, cmdDetail.CommandText, cb, parameterSource);
        IDataReader reader = (IDataReader)state.State;
        dt.Load(reader);
        reader.Close();
      ...
        return await Task.FromResult(dt);
    }
```

I am getting  below Error

**{"The database type "MySqlDatabase" does not support asynchronous operations."}**

Below is the complete stack image of the error..

[image: Stack Trace]

My connection string is

```
 <add name="VirtualCloudDB" providerName="EntLibContrib.Data.MySql" connectionString="database=test;uid=xxx;password=xxx;Data Source=test-instance; maximumpoolsize=3"/>
```

Comment: just remove the async stuff

Comment: Please read the question before you comment, this is what i want to achieve what you suggesting to remove

Comment: I did....

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.beginexecutereader?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

what u will see is none of.....(AsyncCallback ) Plus i dont know if this is compatiable with Mysql have you tried 
https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/08/02/build-a-simple-crud-app-with-aspnetcore-mysql-and-twilio#build-the-home-controller-and-page

Comment: I am following this https://github.com/EnterpriseLibrary .. All Async calls are working fine with Sql server.. but when i use MySql then i get the above error

Comment: @Bezhas that's not the Microsoft Enterprise library, it's a clone of the decades-old EntLib code. **Don't** use it. The data layer functionality was incorporated in ADO.NET 2.0 **15 years** ago - you can use a database-agnostic provider factory already.  The "async" code you used was replaced by Tasks in 2010 and became completely obsolete in 2012 when `async/await` was introduced

Comment: @Bezhas your code doesn't use async calls at all. There was no async/await or even GitHub when EntLib was written. **Remove it completely**. In ADO.NET, you can use [DbCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbcommand.executereaderasync?view=net-5.0) to execute the query and get a reader asynchronously, eg `var reader=await cmdDetail.ExecuteReaderAsync();`.

Comment: Given how old that library is, there's a pretty good chance that the MySQL provider you're trying to use just plain doesn't have the async methods implemented. Is there a specific reason you need to use this library?

Comment: Agreed @PanagiotisKanavos but being an employee of product base company this is already used thoroughly. I can;t replaced this :). Are you talking about this link..  https://github.com/EnterpriseLibrary/data-access-application-block
this is not that old.. it's example are upto date. Yeah, The last release of enterprize library was 2013 and event that lack Task.. they continued with callback approach

Comment: The only thing EntLib Data Layer provided was a "database provider factory" that abstracted the actual classes (SqlCommand, MySqlCommand). That is available through the [ADO.NET Factory API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/obtaining-a-dbproviderfactory). It's not use so much though, because most applications use ORMs like Entity Framework or NHibernate to generate SQL and load objects.

Comment: For quick execution and mapping, libraries like [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper) remove the need for readers and DataTables. A connection object and `IEnumerabl<Products> products=await connection.QueryAsync<Product>("select * from Products");` is all you need

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos .(Reason to use) I have make the api method Task based.. but to get the true benefits of threading  my underlying call had to be asynchronous.. this is why i am trying to acheive.

Comment: @Bezhas that's not what happened. I was actually there. EntLib was created to provide the missing functionality in .NET *1.0*, by providing a database abstraction, a logging layer, exception handling etc. The Data part was completely incorporated into ADO.NET 2.0. Other parts were *way over-engineered* which is why they didn't catch on, or were replaced by other libraries like eg log4net. Microsoft was trying to promote its own CodePlex rival to Github back then, and never would have posted anything to GitHub. Obviously, Codeplex failed and was shut down. What you see is a clode of  old code

Comment: @Bezhas `await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync()` is asynchronous. All MySQL providers implement it, even though Connector/.NET cheats by creating an extra thread - actually using a delegate and calling `BeginInvoke` under the hood, just like you tried to do in your own code. That's no better (actually worse) than using `var reader=await Task.Run(()=>cmd.ExecuteReader())`. It would be even better if you called the entire *synchronous* method with `Task.Run`

Comment: you should really consider just adding Entity Framework, as the start of the migration to a more modern db abstraction.

Comment: @Bezhas besides, you code still loads the data synchronously. There's no async version of `DataTable.Load`. EF Core or Dapper on the other hand will load all the data asynchronously from execution to loading

Comment: @Bezhas as for `I was there` I was an MVP in 2005-2008. I met the creators in Seattle, I bought the books, gave the User Group talks on EntLib *and* ADO.NET 2 later on. *The Entlib creators themselves* added the Data functionality to ADO.NET. Entlib DAB is supported by people like **you** now, people that still have to use it.

Comment: You should *seriously* consider using the open-source [MySqlConnector](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector) library rather than Oracle's Connector/.NET . It offers far better async performance and doesn't have the bugs and quirks the "official" library has. After all, Oracle has no reason to provide a good MySQL provide for .NET. In fact, Connector/.NET stagnated for *years* before the 8.0 release. At first, it didn't even implement the `...Async` methods

Comment: @Bezhas what is `CommandDetail`? There's no such class in Entlib DAAB. It uses ADO.NET's DbCommand. You could be usin the async calls just now if you hadn't wrapped the EntLib classes with you own

Comment: CommandDetail is a custom class having command details like stored procedure name etc..

Comment: @Bezhas *that class* prevents you from using DAAB in the first place. DAAB uses ADO.NET's abstract classes. If you had access to the actual DbCommand you could execute it asynchronously. I added an example in the answer that shows how to use `Database` instead of `DbProviderFactory`. If you check the `Database.cs` file though you'll see it uses `DbProviderFactory` itself, and contains only convenience methods.

Comment: @Bezhas long story short, EntLib DAAB is actually just some convenience methods on top of ADO.NET 2. You could execute the DbCommands it gives you asynchronously if `CommandDetail` didn't hide it.

Comment: @Bezhas oops, I forgot about the actual error -`The database type "MySqlDatabase" does not support asynchronous operations.`. That's *exactly* the error Oracle's provider raised in versions before 8.0. Use MySqlConnector or upgrade to the latest version of Connector/.NET

Comment: The issue still exists with latest release (8.0.24)

Comment: @Bezhas with which methods? People stopped using the APM model 9 years ago. It's quite likely Oracle implemented the `Async` versions but not the `Begin/End` methods. There's simply no need for them. Only .NET Framework 2.0 applications require them, and .NET 2 is out of support. The oldest supported .NET Framework version is 4.5.2 and even that is [going out of support](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-framework-4-5-2-4-6-4-6-1-will-reach-end-of-support-on-april-26-2022/) in 11 months

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos On BeginExecuteReader, I agree with you, I do work in dapper and entity framework core.  At times need to support in the legacy.

Comment: @Bezhas use `DbCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync` then. You're already working with DbCommand. In fact, if you check the Database.cs source you'll see it has `ExecuteReader` methods that work with ready-made commands, raw SQL or stored procedures, and all they do is ... create and populate a DbCommand. You can create an extension method on `Database` that does the same.

Comment: Yes @PanagiotisKanavos, that has one problem.. DbCommand has to gvien the connection string Also the opening and closing has to be very specfic.
I wanted to achieve that with database. But as a last option i would go for that.
thanks alot

Comment: @Bezhas for example [CreateCommandByCommandType](https://github.com/EnterpriseLibrary/data-access-application-block/blob/ff08379d41622e50a47c218319981a372eb54ae9/source/Src/Data/Database.cs#L286) simply calls `DbProviderFactory.CreateCommand`. `CreateConnection` calls `DbProviderFactory.CreateConnection`

Comment: @Bezhas no it doesn't, it needs a DbConnection. Again, DAAB uses the ADO.NET classes. It creates a DbConnection and passes it to a DbCommand. Check the links to the source I just posted. That's plain old ADO.NET code. When you call `Database.ExecuteWhatever`, the code creates a new `DbConnection`, a `DbCommand` with the command text and possibly parameters and calls the appropriate `Execute` method, eg `ExecuteReader` or `ExecuteNonQuery`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**About the error**

Oracle's Connector/.NET library didn't even allow asynchronous operations before v8.0. Even now, there are several quirks. It's better to use the independent, open-source [MySqlConnector](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector) library.

If you absolutely must use Connector/.NET, upgrade to the latest version.

**About the code (no history lesson)**

Forget EntLib, especially DAAB. Even the docs say:

> The `Database` class leverages the provider factory model from ADO.NET. A database instance holds a reference to a concrete `DbProviderFactory` object to which it forwards the creation of ADO.NET objects.

What you use isn't the real thing anyway, it's a community-supported clone of the [official code that used to be stored in Codeplex](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=entlib). The only thing that is still in development is the [Unity DI container](https://github.com/unitycontainer).

Real async operations are available in ADO.NET and implemented by most providers. The database-agnostic, [factory-based model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/obtaining-a-dbproviderfactory) of EntLib 1 was incorporated into ADO.NET 2 back in 2006. Entlib 2.0 DAAB is essentially a thin layer of convenience methods over ADO.NET 2.

**ADO.NET 2 "Raw"**

In ADO.NET 2.0 alone, the entire method can be replaced with :

```
async Task<DataTable> LoadProducts(string category)
{
    var sql="select * from Products where category=@category";
    using(var connection=new MySqlConnection(_connStrFromConfig))
    using(var cmd=new MySqlCommand(sql,connection))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category",category);

        await connection.OpenAsync();

        using(var reader=await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(reader);
            return dt;
        }
    }
}
```

Especially for MySQL, it's better to use the open-source [MySqlConnector](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector) library than Oracle's official Connector/.NET.

**ADO.NET 2 Factory model**

ADO.NET 2 added abstract base classes and a factory model (based on DAAB 1, but easier) that allows using database-agnostic code as much as possible.

The previous code, without using the provider factory, can be rewritten as :

```
string _providerName="MySqlConnector"


DbCommand CreateConnection()
{
    DbProviderFactory _factory =DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(_providerName);
    connection = _factory.CreateConnection();
    connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    return connection;
}

async Task<DataTable> LoadProducts(string category)
{
    var sql="select * from Products where category=@category";
    using(DbConnection connection=CreateConnection())
    using(DbCommand cmd= connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText=sql;
        var param=cmd.CreateParameter();
        param.Name="@category";
        //The default is String, so we don't have to set it
        //param.DbType=DbType.String;
        param.Value=category;
        
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@category",category);

        await connection.OpenAsync();

        using(var reader=await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(reader);
            return dt;
        }
    }
}
```

All that's needed to target eg SQL Server or Oracle is registering and using a different provider name.

The code can be simplified. For example, [DbParameterCollection.AddRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbparametercollection.addrange?view=net-5.0) can be used to add multiple parameters at once. That's still too much code by modern standards though.

**Entlib 2 DAAB - it's the same classes**

Entlib 2 DAAB uses the same abstract classes. In fact, the [Database](https://github.com/EnterpriseLibrary/data-access-application-block/blob/ff08379d41622e50a47c218319981a372eb54ae9/source/Src/Data/Database.cs) class does little more than add convenience methods on top of the abstract classes, eg methods to create a DbCommand, or execute a query and return a reader or a Dataset.

If you didn't need parameters, you could write just :

```
DataTable LoadProducts(Database database)
{
    var sql="select * from Products";
    var set=database.ExecuteDataSet(CommandType.Text,sql);
    return set.Tables[0];
}
```

Unfortunately, there's no way to combine a raw query and parameters. Back when EntLib 1 was created it was thought that complex code should always be stored in a stored procedure. So while there's a `ExecuteDataSet(string storedProcedureName,params object[] parameterValues)`, there's no equivalent for raw SQL.

And no Task-based async methods either. By 2010 EntLib was in support mode already.

*Unfortunately again* there's no way to directly create a DbCommand from Database. Again, the assumption was that people would either execute raw SQL or called a stored procedure. There's a `GetSqlStringCommand` that accepts no parameters. There's also `Database.ProviderFactory` that can be used to do everything manually, and end up with the same code as raw ADO.NET.

Another possible option is to cheat, and use `Database.GetStoredProcCommand` with positional parameters and change the `CommandType`

```
async Task<DataTable> LoadProducts(Database database,string category)
{
    var sql="select * from Products where category=@category";
    using(var cmd=database.GetStoredProcCommand(sql,category))
    {
        cmd.CommandType=CommandType.Text;
        using(var reader=await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(reader);
            return dt;
        }
    }

    return set.Tables[0];
}
```

**Dapper**

With microORM libraries like [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper) the code can be reduced to :

```
async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> LoadProducts(string category)
{
    var sql="select * from Products where category=@category";
    using(var connection=CreateConnection())
    {

        var products=await connection.Query<Product>(sql,new {category=category});

        return products;
    }
}
```

Dapper will open the connection if it's closed, execute the query asynchronously and map the results to the target object, in a single line of code. Parameters will be mapped by name from the parameter object.

When called without a type parameter, `Query` returns a list of `dynamic` objects

```
async Task<IEnumerable<dynamic>> LoadProducts(string category)
{
    var sql="select * from Products where category=@category";
    using(var connection=CreateConnection())
    {

        var products=await connection.Query(sql,new {category=category});

        return products;
    }
}
```